# How to prevent invalid input in paper-input?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How to prevent invalid input in paper-input?

Here is [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uNHM0D2h9D0CbqUioJMu?p=preview) where `preventInvalidInput` is not working as expected,

i.e. even when the `invalid = true`:

- user can continue typing,
- `value` attribute is bound to the incorrect input.

  ```
  <paper-input 
       label="max" 
       type="number" 
       value="{{year_max}}" 
       min="0" 
       max="255" 
       editable

       invalid={{invalid}}
       auto-validate

       prevent-invalid-input

       error-message="Error msg"
  ></paper-input>
  ```

Comment: `preventInvalidInput` only works with `allowedPattern`(RegEx). `Iron-input` element has only regex validations

Answer (score 4):

The `preventInvalidInput` flag only prevents input of "invalid" characters (e.g., if the user typed `a+b+c = d` when only alphanumeric characters were allowed, the `paper-input` would accept only `abcd`). It does *not* prevent further input when the `invalid` flag is set (which is what you seem to expect).

To use `preventInvalidInput`, you must specify which characters are *valid* with [`allowedPattern`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#property-allowedPattern) (a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)), and these properties apply only to `type="text"`. For example, the following `paper-input` allows digits, minus (for negative numbers), and dot (for decimals):

```
<paper-input prevent-invalid-input allowed-pattern="[-.\d]">
```

Your code appears to require only digits, so you would use:

```
<paper-input prevent-invalid-input allowed-pattern="[\d]">
```

or slightly cleaner for single-class patterns:

```
<paper-input prevent-invalid-input allowed-pattern="\d">
```

[modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zKmfmaJgBv7HvvOd4vJF?p=preview)

Comment: In decimal how to restrict only 5 digit ?

Comment: Example 12.12345. it should allow only 5 integers on decimal. How to do that @tony19 any idea bro ?

Comment: @Munna AFAIK, that can't be done with the built-in APIs of `paper-input`. You'd have to extend it with that custom behavior. Maybe someone else might have an idea, so it would be best to ask that as a new question to allow a more helpful answer.